# Build error on jdk.incubator.http's visibility using maven and intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, java-9

I'm trying to use use jdk.incubator.http on maven, but it can not pass build process, the error shown in Intellij IDEA 2017.3

```
Error:(3, 21) java: package jdk.incubator.http is not visible
  (package jdk.incubator.http is declared in module jdk.incubator.httpclient, which is not in the module graph)
```

Pom file's build section is following:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>9</source>
                <target>9</target>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>--add-modules=jdk.incubator.http</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I also can not use module-info.java cause there's issue with the invalid unnamed model name generated according to its file name

Comment: That looks like `java`, not `javac`, is complaining. Are you sure this happens during compilation and not when, e.g., running tests?

Comment: That's what I'm surprised about... this info comes from the "Message build" box in IDEA, and it honestly don't looks like it's compiling using maven though javac. The Event log:Compilation completed with 3 errors and 0 warnings in 4s 572ms;

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you get this error from IntelliJ. Sorry. IntelliJ doesn't apply the compiler arguments you put into the POM to its own compilation. You need to configure that separately within IntelliJ.

Comment: @wusatosi Nicolai is right, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143742.

Comment: Ok..... Thanks for help! another surprisingly fact is that I manage to build successfully once.... but I can't recreate again...... Is there any way to fix it?